# Run time complexity of multiple nested for loops and StringBuilder

Tags: runtime, big-o, calculation

I realize a nested for loop has O(n^2) runtime but what if there are **two** for loops inside the outer for loop as show below? Does this still have an O(n^2) runtime?

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
  for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
  {
   // Some code
  }
  for(p = 1; p <= n; p++)
  {
   // Some code
  }
}
```

Also does string builder have a O(n) runtime to construct a string of size n?

Comment: Your question about `StringBuilder` should be in a separate question. But see here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c0c45944-dcf0-4732-8e87-845fcc1e8f6b/stringbuilder-method-performance?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer loop executes `n` times the two inner loops, which each take `n` steps. So you get `n * 2n = 2n^2` steps, which is `O(n^2)`.